# How many split values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this string

`?( {"entity": {"BusinessName": "FANEUIL HALL APARTMENTS, L.L.C.", "UBI": "601754321", "Category": "LLC", "Type": "Profit", "Active": "Active", "StateOfIncorporation": "WA", "DateOfIncorporation": "12/03/1996", "ExpirationDate": "12/31/2014", "DissolutionDate": "", "RegisteredAgentName": "LESLIE R PESTERFIELD", "RegisteredAgentAddress": "901 FIFTH AVE STE 3500", "RegisteredAgentCity": "SEATTLE", "RegisteredAgentState": "WA", "RegisteredAgentZip": "98164", "AlternateAddress": "", "AlternateCity": "", "AlternateState": "", "AlternateZip": "", "GoverningPersons": [  { "Title": "Manager", "LastName": "HEATHMAN", "MiddleName": "W", "FirstName": "MICHAEL              W", "Address": "", "City": "PALM SPRINGS", "State": "CA", "Zip": "         " } ]}} );`

My goal is to get the `first name`, `middle name`, `last name`, `city`, and `state` returned and arranged all into separate cells on the same row but different columns.

My code works for multiple governing persons but once it becomes a single governing person, it stops working as expected.

I am unable to formula my `Else` part in the below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim names As String

    Values = Split(resp, """GoverningPersons"":")

    If InStr(1, Values(1), "}, {") > 0 Then
        newvalues = Split(Values(1), "}, {")
        x = Split(newvalues(0), """LastName"": ")
        j = Split(x(1), ", ""MiddleName"":")
        m = Split(j(1), ", ""FirstName"":")
        r = j(0) + m(0) + m(1)
        l = Split(m(1), ", ""Address"": ")
        names = l(0)

        If InStr(1, l(0), "  ") > 0 Then
            al = Left(names, InStr(names, "  ") - 1)
            d = al + m(0) + j(0)
        Else
            d = l(0) + m(0) + j(0)
        End If

        a = Replace(d, Chr(32), "")
        g = Replace(a, Chr(34), " ")
    ElseIf InStr(1, Values(1), "[ }}") > 0 Then

    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

I tried everything i could think of and the name never appears like the first portion of my code.

Comment: For the love of god, format your question properly.

Comment: ...and use the correct tags and provide a *minimal* example of the problem.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be cleaned up @thebluedog ?

Comment: I am surprised your code is even compiling... It should fail on `names = l(0)`. The `names` is a reserved word in Excel VBA.

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel-VBA?

Comment: @siddharthrout yeah it does compile I defined it as a string. im obviously not a macro wiz so i wasnt aware of that it was more dumb luck i guess. Yes I am using excel-vba

Comment: That again is a bad idea :) You shouldn't be using reserved words as variables. Cann you show what output you are expecting and what exactly are you getting?

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the tip and yeah its just the name really for the data above it would return "MICHAEL W HEATHMAN" as far as what im getting, nothing it says my x split is out of range.

Comment: So you want to extract First name, middle name, last name, city, and state from above?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started.

Here I have shown you how to extract the `First name`, `middle name` and `last name`. I am sure you can apply the same logic to extract the `city` and `state`.

**Note**: I have not included any error handling. i am sure you will take care of that?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim resp As String
    Dim Lastname As String, Midname As String, Firstname As String

    '~~> For testing purpose, I stored the json string in Cell A1
    resp = Range("A1").Value

    '~~> This will give you last name
    Lastname = GetValue(resp, """LastName"":")
    Debug.Print "Lastname :" & Lastname

    '~~> This will give you middle name
    Midname = GetValue(resp, """MiddleName"":")
    Debug.Print "Middle Name :" & Midname

    '~~> This will give you First name
    Firstname = GetValue(resp, """FirstName"":")
    Debug.Print "First Name :" & Firstname
End Sub

Function GetValue(sString As String, sDelim As String) As String
    Dim MyArray, tmpAr

    MyArray = Split(sString, sDelim)
    tmpAr = Split(MyArray(1), ",")
    GetValue = Trim(Replace(tmpAr(0), Chr(34), ""))
End Function
```

**ScreenShot**

**Excel Sheet**

[image]

**VBA Editor**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it (requires a little javascript/JSON knowledge)

```
Sub tester()

'add project reference to "Microsoft script control"
Dim so As New ScriptControl
Dim i As Integer, num As Integer
Dim js As String, json As String

    so.Language = "jscript"


    json = "{""entity"": {""BusinessName"": ""FANEUIL HALL APARTMENTS, L.L.C."", " & _
        " ""UBI"": ""601754321"", ""Category"": ""LLC"", ""Type"": ""Profit"", ""Active"": " & _
        " ""Active"", ""StateOfIncorporation"": ""WA"", ""DateOfIncorporation"": " & _
        " ""12/03/1996"", ""ExpirationDate"": ""12/31/2014"", ""DissolutionDate"": """", " & _
        " ""RegisteredAgentName"": ""LESLIE R PESTERFIELD"", ""RegisteredAgentAddress"": " & _
        " ""901 FIFTH AVE STE 3500"", ""RegisteredAgentCity"": ""SEATTLE"", " & _
        " ""RegisteredAgentState"": ""WA"", ""RegisteredAgentZip"": ""98164"", " & _
        " ""AlternateAddress"": """", ""AlternateCity"": """", ""AlternateState"": """", " & _
        " ""AlternateZip"": """", ""GoverningPersons"": [  { ""Title"": ""Manager"", " & _
        " ""LastName"": ""HEATHMAN"", ""MiddleName"": ""W"", ""FirstName"": ""MICHAEL W"", " & _
        " ""Address"": """", ""City"": ""PALM SPRINGS"", ""State"": ""CA"", ""Zip"": """" } ]}}"

     so.AddCode "var o = eval(" & json & ");"

     num = so.Eval("o.entity.GoverningPersons.length") ' >> 1

     For i = 0 To num - 1
        js = "o.entity.GoverningPersons[" & i & "]."
        Debug.Print so.Eval(js & "LastName;")
        Debug.Print so.Eval(js & "FirstName;")
        Debug.Print so.Eval(js & "MiddleName;")
        'etc
     Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Where would I best aquire a little JSON/javascript knowledge?

Comment: @tbur - JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON   Javascript is a much bigger topic...